# Как отправить Request $request для функции Laravel вручную?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть функция, которую я хотел бы вызывать и вручную и так же отправлением POST на роут.
Но из-за своей глупости получается 2 функции вместо одной

```
function foo(Request $request) {
    $foo = $request->foo;
}

function bar($data = []) {
    $foo = $data['foo'];
}
```

Вопрос: Как сделать функцию универсальной для обоих случаев, или как вручную собрать объект Request чтобы передать его в аргумент?

Answer (score 0):

Создаете папку `Services` в `app`
Там создаете класс, например `FooService`

```
public function makeFoo ($request = null) {
 //если ничего не передавать в метод - то реквест будет пустота, если передашь - будет реквест
 // делаем свои дела и возвращаем результат
 return $result;
}
```

Дальше два случая

Когда в контроллере, допустим это `BarController`, нужно сделать манипуляции с реквестом:

```
public function workWithRequest(Request $request, BarService $barService) {
           $result = $barService->makeFoo($request)
 }
```

Когда в контроллере просто нужно сделать манипуляции без реквеста:

```
public function workWithRequest(BarService $barService) {
               $result = $barService->makeFoo()
     }
```